# Getting only [ ] (brackets) when using find_all with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Getting started with Beautifulsoup and find_all doesn't seem to be finding much of anything. Setup code is following a tutorial. My end goal is to eventually scrape images from Pinterest. My code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.pinterest.com'
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

soup.find_all("img")
```

Result is:

```
[]
```

I've tried replacing "img" with "div" to see if I could find anything else. It works, but only returns the very first "div" out of probably hundreds on the page:

```
>>> soup.find_all("div")
[<div data-reactcontainer="true" id="__PWS_ROOT__"></div>]
```

[PinterestHTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1mK9.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the BeautifulSoup object that you get there are no img tags you can see by

```
print(set([tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()]))
```

return

```
{'body', 'div', 'head', 'html', 'link', 'meta', 'script', 'title'}
```

This is all tags that you have in the `soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")`.

Comment: Thanks, that clues me into what find_all is seeing. But why is it only seeing those tags when there are definitely more on the page? And why would find_all only be returning 1 div result when there are much more?

Comment: This is the count of tags from the page {'link': 43, 'meta': 31, 'script': 16, 'html': 1, 'head': 1, 'title': 1, 'body': 1, 'div': 1} there is only 1 div.

Comment: There's a link to an image of the html I see on that website in the original question. There's a bunch of div tags, and within those are other tags like "a" and "img". Does BeautifulSoup not see the same thing? Is there something I'm missing that might allow BeautifulSoup to see what I'm seeing when I inspect the html?

Comment: The a and img tags that you are seeing are from the links tags and not in the html of the page that you are looking on.